# node.js how to wait till async operation is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
function donwloadFromBucket() {
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage();
    const options = {  destination: "c:/tmp/dw.js", };

  await storage
    .bucket("pipelines-models")
    .file("index.js")
    .download(options);  }
}

donwloadFromBucket();

nextOperations();
```

I want the donwloadFromBucket function to complete and only then to proceed to the function nextOperations.

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: async main function(){
donwloadFromBucket();

nextOperations();
} 
main()

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this ,in second async function ,next oprations won't execute unless `donwloadFromBucket();` completes.Also you have can use `await` only in `async` function,your `donwloadFromBucket();` is not async.

```
 async function donwloadFromBucket() {
        const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
        const storage = new Storage();
        const options = {  destination: "c:/tmp/dw.js", };

    return await storage  //  return something here ,to make the function finish completion.
        .bucket("pipelines-models")
        .file("index.js")
        .download(options);  }
    }


    async function second()
    {
    await donwloadFromBucket();

    nextOperations();

    }
 second(); // call the second function
```

Something note worthy-

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.
>   [Follow up Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: i think the first async await is useless

Comment: Well that's how it is mentioned in the question.He has to make it async to achieve what he is looking otherwise ,event loop will execute it accordingly